# Entity Framework two level filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following column in a table:

```
OrderId
CustomerId
TimeZoneOffset   <-- in minutes
DateOrderUTC     <-- This field is indexed
...
```

When the user filters the date, I need to consider the timezone of the order. I know, I can just create DateOrder without UTC (which used their timezone when creating order). But this is the DB given to me.

This table contains about 2 million records. If I used the following code, it will not use an index seek as it needs to add timezone.

```
return (from rec in dbctx.tblApprovalReferralPromoUsers.AsNoTracking()
        where (DbFunctions.AddMinutes(rec.DateOrderUTC, rec.TimeZoneOffset) >= startDate) && (DbFunctions.AddMinutes(rec.DateOrderUTC, rec.TimeZoneOffset) <= endDate)
        select rec).Count();
```

So, my idea is to add -1 day for startDate and +1 day for endDate to trick the optimizer to use the index. So, the code looks like something like this:

```
startDate = startDate.AddDays(-1);
endDate = endDate.AddDays(1);
var vRecs = (from rec in dbctx.tblApprovalReferralPromoUsers.AsNoTracking()
             where (rec.DateOrderUTC >= startDate) && (rec.DateOrderUTC <= endDate)
             select rec);
return ???;
```

I don't want to return the list first because it can be hundreds of thousands of records. How to do another filter here before returning the Count?

Comment: A DateTime is stored as a number in UTC.  The timezone is used when converting a string to a DateTime as the default offset.  If you make startDate DateTime.Parse("3/19/2023") it will get converted to UTC so when comparing against the DateTime in db you do not need to add an offset.  Same for End Date.

Comment: Problem is that the filter date should only display those records that belong to the filter date - based on the given timezone offset of the date. So the filter date is not in UTC

Comment: Then filter on timezone which is just a number between -12 and +12 along with between start and end date.  Yes you may need to offset start and end date for a different timezone.  Most business operating in more than one timezone (or 24/7) standardizes a Business Day which may be more than one actual day. A business day may start at 4:00AM EST.

Comment: Yes, I used +1 and -1 day just to be safe. With daylight saving, it can be +14 hours. If I can work out to do 2 filters, then adding +1 and -1 day will be negligible. But of course, I can improve it by using +- 15 hours to be safe instead of +-1 day...

Comment: I think adding a day is just going to cause more issues.  DateTime Parse automatically account for  daylight saving time except on day when transition occurs.

Comment: It is just for temporary date to trick the system so it can use the index seek instead of index scan

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another `where` clause, or even compose it in a second query.

```
var qRec1 = from rec in dbctx.tblApprovalReferralPromoUsers.AsNoTracking()
            where (rec.DateOrderUTC >= startDate) && (rec.DateOrderUTC <= endDate)
            select rec;

var qRec2 = from rec in qRec1
            where (DbFunctions.AddMinutes(rec.DateOrderUTC, rec.TimeZoneOffset) >= startDate) && (DbFunctions.AddMinutes(rec.DateOrderUTC, rec.TimeZoneOffset) <= endDate)
            select rec;

var count = qRec2.Count();
```

but you should really use a single query and convert the startDate/endDate to UTC, that way you don't wrap the column expression in a non-SARGable expression, and can use the index.

```
var qRec = from rec in dbctx.tblApprovalReferralPromoUsers.AsNoTracking()
            where rec.DateOrderUTC >= DbFunctions.AddMinutes(startDate, -rec.TimeZoneOffset) 
               && rec.DateOrderUTC < DbFunctions.AddMinutes(endDate,-rec.TimeZoneOffset) 
            select rec;
```

Comment: If you look at LINQPad, it generates the exact same query in `qRec2` as the SQL generated on the 2nd query. On the 2nd query, it will not use index seek but use index scan. This is because it needs to read each record to get the actual timezone as SQL has nowhere to know if the timezone of each record is the same or not.